# How to authorize Google Analytics Query Explorer 2

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the [Google Analytics Query Explorer 2](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to test a few API calls, but it says I need to authorize myself and I don't know where to do that. What am I missing? [Here is a screenshot.](http://s28.postimg.org/hy4m7r9a5/Screen_Shot_2014_01_08_at_12_40_07.png)

Comment: tip: disable adblock on this site and you'll see the authorize button

Answer (score 0):

Try the big button on the right that says "Authorize Access"

[image]

Im not sure whats wrong with your screenshot but https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ has the button.  your screenshot doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

The site was [recently designed](https://plus.google.com/111224383669619377607/posts/Fbjpp3dLmKh), and it looks like you've somehow got an old version of the layout with a new version of the stylesheet. If you refresh the page, I'm sure the problem will go away.

And in case it's not obvious, you can authorize the new version by clicking on the big orange banner that says **Click here to authorize**. That will authorize the query explorer as well as all the other demos and tools on the site:

[image]